# Click event after autocomplete display from php array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I can't find a solution for a easy jquery/php script with autocomplete.
When I enter a city autocomplete ask php page (with mysql dbb) and return an array ($suggestions['suggestions'][]) with multiple result and display it.

I would like to do an alert() when I click on one result, but it doesn't work :(

jQuery

```
$('#search-city').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'mod/search-city.php?action=city',
    dataType: 'json',
    select: function() {
     alert("OK");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="search-city" id="search-city" value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" autocomplete="off">
```

An idea ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is the ajax request successfully completing and returning back data?

Comment: Yes  http://demo.ovh.eu/fr/e815212138e01f74afd3d8c0f56bec01/

Comment: I suppose this is the jquery UI Autocompleter?

Comment: It's this version https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace `select` option to `onSelect`

```
$('#search-city').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'mod/search-city.php?action=city',
    dataType: 'json',
    onSelect: function() {
     alert("OK");
    }
});
```